# jquery remove parent of <li> tag

Tags: visual-c++

```
$("#yourOrderFoodsItems ul").on('click','.deleteFood',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

;

If the

isn't the direct parent, you can use closest:

```
$("#yourOrderFoodsItems ul").on('click','.deleteFood',function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});

Live DEMO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#yourOrderFoodsItems ul").on('click','.deleteFood',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

If the `<li>` isn't the direct parent, you can use `closest`:

```
$("#yourOrderFoodsItems ul").on('click','.deleteFood',function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8khjE/)

Comment: i did that and nothing happend when press the `.deleteFood`

Comment: @SimeoniPeraparota, If it's not the direct parent you will need to use `closest` as I wrote.

Comment: even the closest not working, i add alter to the function but nothing alter, maybe it is not fired, right?

Comment: @SimeoniPeraparota, I added a demo, see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: when i added the <li><div class='deleteFood'> explicit it works, but the elemetns those added from jquery not working with, why please?